# JUnit test method comparing DateTimes fails only when run from suites

Tags: java, junit, java-7, junit4

A single JUnit test being run under JUnit 4.11 fail the majority of the time while being run via either to module test suite (**40 runs: 2 failures, 38 passes**), or the class test suite (**40 runs: 6 failures, 34 passes**), but running the test method by itself did not produce a single failure (**50 runs: 0 failures, 50 passes**).

To summarize what is happening, the `equals(Object MyObject)` implementation returns `true` if the `org.joda.time.DateTime` corresponding to the key `Stamp.START`  or the key `Stamp.STOP` is the same for the current instance as the one in instance passed to the method. Here's the code:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
...
private final Map<Stamp, DateTime> timeStampMap;
...
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) { return true; }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }
    final MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
    return (Objects.equals(this.timeStampMap.get((Stamp.START)),
                           other.timeStampMap.get(Stamp.START))
            && Objects.equals(this.timeStampMap.get(Stamp.STOP),
                              this.timeStampMap.get(Stamp.STOP)));
}
...
public enum Stamp {
    START,
    STOP
}
```

And the test itself:

```
@Test
@Config(configuration = TestConfig.NO_CONFIG)
public void equalityTest() {
    MyObject a = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);
    MyObject b = a;

    assertThat(a.hashCode(), is(b.hashCode()));
    assertTrue(a.equals(b));

    b = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);

    // This line produces the failure
    assertThat(a, is(not(b)));
}
```

Why would this test only fail when run under either test suite, but not when run on it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the process of trying to produce an MCVE and author the question, I discovered something interesting:

When the test is run at the method level, note the timestamp difference of 1 millisecond. The difference is never less than that:

```
[START: 2015-02-26T11:53:20.581-06:00, STOP: 2015-02-26T11:53:20.641-06:00, DURATION: 0.060]    
[START: 2015-02-26T11:53:20.582-06:00, STOP: 2015-02-26T11:53:20.642-06:00, DURATION: 0.060]
```

But when I run the test ends up being run as part of the suites, this happens nearly every single time:

```
[START: 2015-02-26T12:25:31.183-06:00, STOP: 2015-02-26T12:25:31.243-06:00, DURATION: 0.060]
[START: 2015-02-26T12:25:31.183-06:00, STOP: 2015-02-26T12:25:31.243-06:00, DURATION: 0.060]
```

***Zero difference.*** Weird right?

***My best guess*** is that the JVM is proverbially all warmed up and has some momentum built by the time it reaches this particular test when running the test suites. So much so, that the instantiations occur so quickly as to be nearly simultaneous. The tiny amount of time that passes between the time that `MyObject a` is instantiated and `b` is assigned until `b` is reassigned as a new `MyObject` is so minute as to produce a `MyObject` with an identical pair of `DateTime`s.

Turns out, there are a few usable solutions:

### The Solution I Went With:

This is really similar to [Duncan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762195/2293700). Call [`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisOffset(val)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisOffset(long)) before reassigning `MyObject b` and then reset immediately afterward, since I only need the offset long enough to force a difference in the `DateTimes` between `MyObjects` `a` and `b`:

```
@Test
@Config(configuration = TestConfig.NO_CONFIG)
public void equalityTest() {
    MyObject a = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);
    MyObject b = a;

    assertThat(a.hashCode(), is(b.hashCode()));
    assertTrue(a.equals(b));

    // Force an offset
    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisOffset(1000);
    b = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);
    // Clears the offset
    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem();

    assertThat(a, is(not(b)));
}
```

## [Namshubwriter's Solution (link to answer):](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778478/2293700)

Easily the best solution in cases where this issue will likely be seen throughout a project and/or in actual use.

### [Duncan's Solution (link to answer):](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762195/2293700)

Set the current time to return a fixed time by calling [`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(val)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed(long)) at the beginning of the unit test, then adding an offset to that time by calling `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(val + someOffset)` to force the difference before reassigning `MyObject b`. Click the link to jump right to his solution with the code.

It is worth pointing out that you'll need to call `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem()` at some point to reset the time, otherwise other tests dependent on the time could be affected.

#### Original Solution:

*I think it is worth mentioning here that, it is my understanding this is the only solution that does not depend on the program having certain security privileges on the parent system.*

Place a call to `Thread.sleep()` ensure that there is a time separation between the `DateTime` timestamps of the two `MyObjects`:

```
@Test
@Config(configuration = TestConfig.NO_CONFIG)
public void equalityTest() {
    MyObject a = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);
    MyObject b = a;

    assertThat(a.hashCode(), is(b.hashCode()));
    assertTrue(a.equals(b));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(0, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    b = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);

    // Line that was failing
    assertThat(a, is(not(b)));
}
```

Comment: What you mean by warming up the JVM is probably the just in time compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Joda time, an alternative approach might be to fix the current time to something of your choosing using [`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(val)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed(long)).

For example:

```
@Test
@Config(configuration = TestConfig.NO_CONFIG)
public void equalityTest() {
    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(someValue);

    MyObject a = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);
    MyObject b = a;

    assertThat(a.hashCode(), is(b.hashCode()));
    assertTrue(a.equals(b));

    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(someValue + someOffset);

    b = new MyObject(BigDecimal.TEN);

    // This line produces the failure
    assertThat(a, is(not(b)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making the code more testable. Instead of having the code get the date directly, you can pass in an interface named `Clock`:

```
public interface Clock {
  DateTime now();
}
```

Then you could add `Clock` to the constructor:

```
MyObject(BigDecimal bigDecimal, Clock clock) {
  timeStampMap.put(Stamp.START, clock.now());
}
```

For production code, you can make a helper constructor:

```
MyObject(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
  this(bigDecimal, new SystemClock());
}
```

...where `SystemClock` looked like this:

```
public class SystemClock implements Clock {

  @Override
  public DateTime now() {
    return new DateTime();
  }
}
```

Your tests could either mock `Clock` or you could create a fake clock implementation.

Comment: I do not see how this makes the code more testable. I understand the concept, but it only looks like extra boilerplate to me. An unnecessary level of abstraction. Can I convince you to elaborate a little more on how it makes the code more testable? I am having some trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @nihilon the dependencies of your class are explicit. Depending on the clock directly makes the tests invisibly dependent on the clock. Also, if you use a dependency injection framework, it is very little extra code (you don't need the helper constructor). You write the `Clock` classes once, then any class that needs one adds one constructor arg and one field. Finally, your tests can simulate the exact time passing, which makes some kinds of tests less flaky.

Comment: Forgive me, but I am really new at all this. How does abstracting the dependency by just inserting a proverbial middle-class and an interface make it more testable? That still doesn't make any sense to me, if only because all it does is move from using `new DateTime()` to `new SystemClock()` which in turn calls `Clock.now()` which simply returns the `DateTime` I was looking for to begin with. All I see there is making something more complicated than it needs to be simply to make the dependency more 'invisible', and still no reason why that makes it more testable.

Comment: Ok. So let me make sure I understand you: Are you saying that it would make simulating the amount of time that has passed more controllable?

@NamshubWriter

Comment: @nihilon yes. For example, you can inject a fake `Clock` that incremented the time every time it was called

Comment: That's an interesting point. I appreciate the extra insight and you taking to time to teach me something new about writing testable code. However, I think this approach is a little heavy handed for simply forcing a separation in the `DateTime`s in a single test. Since, in use, `MyObject`s will only ever be instantiated by a user clicking a button, I highly doubt this will ever become an issue outside of the scope of this test.